# Get array row and column number according to values in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example I have a `5*5 np.array` like this:

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5],
   [6,7,8,9,10],
   [11,12,13,14,15],
   [16,17,18,19,20],
   [21,22,23,24,25]]
```

if I want to get the range of row and column where `number<=15`, how can I do this?

On the contrary, if I know the range of row and column, like `i` in `xrange(1,4)` and `j` in `xrange(1,4)`, how can I get the number like:

```
[[7,8,9],
 [12,13,14],
 [17,18,19]]
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the first question (*"if I want to get the range of row and column where number<=15, how can I do this?"*). For the second question: try `a[1:4, 1:4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the range based on a condition, you can either apply the condition directly, or use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
>>> a < 15
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(a < 15)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

In the latter case, the return value is a tuple of the matching indices.

To achieve the opposite operation, you can simply slice your array :

```
>>> ar[1:4, 1:4]
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: What does the np.where output mean? And how can I get the number of row and column? For example, if I want value<=15, the row is (0,3) and the column is (0,5)

Comment: @JiaoLi The output is a tuple of all matching elements in the array. If you take them together one by one, from left to right, it means that `a[0,0]` matches the condition, so does `a[0,1]`... Up to `a[2,3]`, `2` and `3` being the last elements of both arrays. Those are actually the "coordinates" of every `True` value in the other example.

Comment: Another question, if I want np.where( 0<x<15), how can I do?

Comment: @JiaoLi You can do `(a > 0) & (a < 15)` and `np.where((a > 0) & (a < 15))`. However next time please consider putting all information in your question, or posting a new question, instead of asking in the comments.